# Transformar linha em colunas usando pivot

Tags: oracle, pivot

Tenho essa lista que é resultante da query mais abaixo:

[image: fazer o pivotamento dessa query mas realmente não consigo:]

Essa é a query:

```
SELECT PERIODO, ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR, Sum (NU_TOTAL_VENDA) AS NU_TOTAL_VENDA
FROM (
      SELECT
        UPAI.ST_NOME AS ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR,
        To_Char(A.DT_CRIADO_EM,'HH24') || ':00' AS PERIODO,
        CASE A.NU_SITUACAO_SUBSTATUS
          WHEN 2 THEN 1
          WHEN 3 THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END AS NU_TOTAL_VENDA
      FROM TB_ATENDIMENTO A
        INNER JOIN TB_USUARIO U ON (U.ID_USUARIO = A.ID_CRIADO_POR)
          LEFT JOIN TB_USUARIO UPAI ON (UPAI.ID_USUARIO = U.NU_CODIGO_PAI)
      WHERE A.DT_CRIADO_EM >= To_Date('05/10/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            AND A.DT_CRIADO_EM <= To_Date('05/10/2020 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            AND A.ID_OPERACAO = 8
            AND (U.NU_CODIGO_PAI IN(4365,4366)
                                    OR Nvl(0,'0') = '0'
                                  )
    )
GROUP BY PERIODO, ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR
UNION
SELECT LPad(PERIODO, 2, '0') || ':00' AS PERIODO, NULL AS ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR, 0 AS NU_TOTAL_VENDA
FROM (
      WITH DEMO AS (SELECT 0 AS "0", 0 AS "1", 0 AS "2", 0 AS "3", 0 AS "4", 0 AS "5", 0 AS "6", 0 AS "7", 0 AS "8", 0 AS "9", 0 AS "10", 0 AS "11", 0 AS "12", 0 AS "13", 0 AS "14", 0 AS "15", 0 AS "16", 0 AS "17", 0 AS "18", 0 AS "19", 0 AS "20", 0 AS "21", 0 AS "22", 0 AS "23" FROM DUAL )
      SELECT * FROM DEMO
      UNPIVOT
      ( VALOR FOR PERIODO IN ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23") )
      )
WHERE PERIODO BETWEEN 8 AND 20
AND PERIODO NOT IN (
                      SELECT To_Number(To_Char(A.DT_CRIADO_EM,'HH24'))
                      FROM TB_ATENDIMENTO A
                        INNER JOIN TB_USUARIO U ON (U.ID_USUARIO = A.ID_CRIADO_POR)
                          LEFT JOIN TB_USUARIO UPAI ON (UPAI.ID_USUARIO = U.NU_CODIGO_PAI)
                      WHERE A.DT_CRIADO_EM >= To_Date('05/10/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                        AND A.DT_CRIADO_EM <= To_Date('05/10/2020 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                        AND A.ID_OPERACAO = 8
                        AND (U.NU_CODIGO_PAI IN(4365,4366)
                                                OR Nvl(0,'0') = '0'
                                              )
                      GROUP BY To_Char(A.DT_CRIADO_EM,'HH24')
                      )
ORDER BY PERIODO, ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR ;
```

É possível transformar as linhas em colunas aplicando o pivot ? Eu até fiz como pode-se notar, mas agora tá complexo, já tentei e estou uns 2 dias nessa query e nada, alguém pode me ajudar ? 
a Lista deve ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use pivot https://www.oracle.com/br/technical-resources/articles/pivot-and-unpivot-feature-oracle-db.html   ou case   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860093/creating-a-pivot-summary-view-using-sql-case-statement   não sendo dinamico é relativamente simples.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal a seguinte solução:

```
WITH 
    HOURS AS (
        SELECT LEVEL AS PERIOD
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 24
),
    TABLE_A AS (
        SELECT
            UPAI.ST_NOME AS ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR,
            To_Char(A.DT_CRIADO_EM,'HH24') || ':00' AS PERIODO,
            CASE A.NU_SITUACAO_SUBSTATUS
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS NU_TOTAL_VENDA
        FROM TB_ATENDIMENTO A
            INNER JOIN TB_USUARIO U ON (U.ID_USUARIO = A.ID_CRIADO_POR)
            LEFT JOIN TB_USUARIO UPAI ON (UPAI.ID_USUARIO = U.NU_CODIGO_PAI)
        WHERE TRUNC(A.DT_CRIADO_EM) = To_Date('05/10/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
          AND A.ID_OPERACAO = 8
          AND (U.NU_CODIGO_PAI IN (4365, 4366)
               OR Nvl(0, '0') = '0'
          )
),
    TABLE_B AS (
        SELECT TO_NUMBER(To_Char(A.DT_CRIADO_EM,'HH24')) TIME_B
        FROM TABLE_A
        GROUP BY To_Char(A.DT_CRIADO_EM,'HH24')
),
    FINAL_TABLE AS (
        SELECT PERIODO, ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR, SUM(NU_TOTAL_VENDA) AS NU_TOTAL_VENDA
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM TABLE_A
            )
        GROUP BY PERIODO, ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR
        UNION
        SELECT LPAD(PERIODO, 2, '0') || ':00' AS PERIODO, NULL AS ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR, 0 AS NU_TOTAL_VENDA
        FROM (
            SELECT * FROM HOURS
        )
        WHERE PERIODO BETWEEN 8 AND 20
        AND PERIODO NOT IN (SELECT TIME_B FROM TABLE_B)
        ORDER BY PERIODO, ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM FINAL_TABLE
) PIVOT (SUM(NU_TOTAL_VENDA) FOR  ST_NOME_SUPERVISOR IN ('LETICIA', 'ALFREDO', 'CARLOS', (...)))
ORDER BY 1
;
```

FIz algumas alterações para simplificar a pesquisa original e tornar tudo mais legível.

A primeira é evitar repetir pesquisas. A tabela referida com `TABLE_A` é a base para as pesquisas subsequentes. Referenciado-a com um `WITH` a pesquisa ficam mais pequena e legível.

A segunda é a forma de restringuir o periodo (inicialmente com um recurso a `UNPIVOT`) ficou mais pequena.

Por último, a tabela pretendida é feita com recurso à cláusula `PIVOT`. Os nomes pretendidos tem de ser enumerados um a um. Mesmo que se pretendam todos tem de ser enumerados o que pode ser aborrecido mas, para o formato normal, o Oracle não permite a utilização do `*` para a enumeração das colunas em `PIVOT` (mas para o formato `XML` já o permite usando palavra chave `ANY` - vá se lá perceber porquê).

Comment: muito interessante a sua sugestão vou aplicar aqui na minha procedure e em seguida vou dar um retorno aqui, obrigado por enquanto.